# ParseInt NumberFormatException on phone number

Tags: java, string, parsing, integer

I'm getting the following error when trying to parse the phone number, "5554567899"

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5554567899"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
...
```

Obviously, the phone number is able to be parsed.  I even referenced [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366257/numberformatexception-on-valid-number-string), and the byte code result was

```
53,53,53,52,53,54,55,56,57,57,
```

So there's no invisible characters in the string.  I'm stumped, can anyone help?

Here's the section of the code that's throwing the error, for reference:

```
String fullNumber = null;
        for(Phone phone : party.getPhones()) {
            if(phone != null && !phone.getDialNumber().isEmpty()) {
                if(!phone.getAreaCode().isEmpty()) {
                    fullNumber = phone.getAreaCode();
                }
                fullNumber += phone.getDialNumber();
                if(phone1 == null || phone1.equals(0)) {
                    LOGGER.debug(displayCharValues(fullNumber));
                    phone1 = Integer.parseInt(fullNumber);
                }
         }
```

`phone1` is of `Java.lang.Integer` type.

Comment: Phone numbers are not numbers. They're strings. For a start, they can begin with one or several zeros. Or a +.

Comment: You shouldn't treat phone number as integer. Treat it as string and if you are saving it into DB, save it as `VARCHAR`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value exceeds the int range. Parse it into a long variable.

Simple test:

```
int i = 5554567899;
```

is a compile time error: "The literal 5554567899 of type int is out of range"

Comment: Dangit, I looked up the range of int, and simply counted digits...I'm dumb, thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Really a phone number shouldn't be treated as a number at all, but as a string or possibly as a datatype that you define yourself, breaking out the country code, area code, exchange, etc.

If you want to validate that it contains only numbers or numbers plus some of the standard phone-number separators, this can be done by regular expressions.

We call it a phone number, and it is a numeric string, but as the usage isn't for numeric computation, you're better off never trying to treat it as a number.

The same goes for "social security numbers".

Answer (score 1):

5554567899 as a number is too big to fit in an int. Try `Long.parseLong` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`5554567899` exceeds [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) (2147483647). Use `Long` or `BigInteger` instead:

```
BigInteger bigNumber = new BigInteger("5554567899");
```