# Exception : java.lang.NumberFormatException When convert String to long

Tags: java

I am converting the string which have '1520056800` to long to have date. But I am getting NumberFormatException to convert this

Please help me.

```
long expiryDateMS = Long.parseLong(responseArray[0].replaceAll(" ", ""));
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
Date date = new Date(expiryDateMS);
```

Stack trace

```
09-02 00:52:28.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12025): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 1520056800
09-02 00:52:28.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12025):    at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:353)
09-02 00:52:28.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12025):    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:344)
09-02 00:52:28.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12025):    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:311)
09-02 00:52:28.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12025):    at com.example.astrill_openvpn.MainOnOffActivity.onCreate(MainOnOffActivity.java:99)
09-02 00:52:28.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12025):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-02 00:52:28.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12025):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

Comment: I'm 100% sure you have some invalid non-printable (so you don't see it) character in your string, if i use `long expiryDateMS = Long.parseLong("1520 056800 ".replaceAll(" ", ""));` it works, so please check `responseArray[0]` contents

Comment: @BackSlash I have checked the content..its `1520056800`

Comment: that's my guess too! maybe some cr lf which you don't see

Comment: Maybe you should break your chained call into two statements so you can see what you're trying to parse.  You don't save anything by combining them, you know.  But you greatly increase debugging difficulty.

Comment: @Android re-check my comment, i said ***invalid non-printable (so you don't see it)*** Loop through your string and print every character. Or maybe just print `responseArray[0].replaceAll(" ", "").length()`, if it will output something greater than `10` you have invalid characters in it.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have invisible or invalid characters in the string.
Try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366257/numberformatexception-on-valid-number-string) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the job. So I'm guessing you have got some encoding/special character problem. Try this to verify you have a real ASCII encoded number:

```
String str = responseArray[0].replaceAll(" ", "");
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
{
    char a = str.charAt(i);
    if (!('0' <= a && a <= '9')) System.out.println(a + " is not a valid digit!");
}
```

Comment: I checked and str is `1520056800`. I think every digit in this is valid digit

Comment: I am using this `SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");` then it diplaying the date `1970-44-18`..Its wrong. Please help to fix it

Comment: Use `yyyy-MM-dd` instead. `mm` is minute. `MM` is month.