# Number format exception when parsing string to long

Tags: java, string, long-integer

I am trying to parse string to long as follows:

```
Long _id_long= Long.valueOf(_id);
```

The error message:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "DT31988159"   at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)

Comment: "DT" should not be part of the string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366257/numberformatexception-on-valid-number-string...try this for more info

Comment: That string isn't a valid long. It has characters that aren't numbers.

Comment: @Asaf: so, it means that it's impossible to parse "DT31988159" to long?

Comment: Yes, you have to remove all the non numeric characters. For example:

_id = _id.replaceAll("DT","");

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the JavaDoc of [`Long.valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))? You will find [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html).

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

[Just remove the prefix.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10372905/3453226)